# Responsive Drop Down - hide menu after click

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I'm using the responsive drop down menu from CSS-Tricks

[Responsive Menu Concepts](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-menu-concepts)

I'd like for the menu to disappear after the user clicks a link. It's a responsive one page web site, so after the link is clicked the user is scrolled down to the content in question.

**How could I automatically hide the menu after a click has been made?**

Though the menu is currently CSS only, I have no qualms on adding javascript if it's needed.

Here is the html

```
<div class="nav-container">
    <nav class="three columns" role="custom-dropdown">
        <input type="checkbox" id="button">
        <label for="button" onclick></label>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#header"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#aboutus"><span>About SoEmi</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#massage"><span>Massage</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#special"><span>Specials</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#mobile"><span>Mobile Spa</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#appointment"><span>Appointment</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#where"><span>Find Us</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I modifed the code below from frenchie and fixed the issue. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.nav-container').on({

   click: function () { $("#button").prop("checked", false); }

}, 'a');
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need javascript for this because you need to handle an event.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.nav-container').on({

       click: function () { $('.nav-container').hide(); }

    }, 'a');

});
```

Make sure you have `jQuery` on the page.

Comment: What would I need to put into the selector field? I'll edit in the code for my nav.

Comment: What do you mean with "the selector field"?

Comment: You said it would be impossible to know what would go in the    'selector' I was asking what to edit into the code you provided. Thank you by the way,

Comment: That didn't appear to work. It may be a javascript conflict. Would a link to the test site in question help?

Comment: Sorry, it did work I was putting in Wordpress and accidentally placed it outside of the noconflict fix. Thank you. This solved my issue.

Comment: BTW, if the answer works, you should mark it as accepted and start building some reputation points so that your future questions get answered.

Comment: I modified your code a bit and it worked.
`$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.nav-container').on({

       click: function () { $("#button").prop("checked", false); }

    }, 'a');

});`